# Redirect One Controller to another Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two controllers users & movies. All, I want to do, redirect from user#something to movie#something. is it possible??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Look at redirect_to.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Comment: Yes, you can do that. `redirect_to post_url(@post)`

Answer (score 24):

```rb
redirect_to controller: :controller_name, action: :action_name
```

Where `controller_name` is the name of your controller and `action_name` is the name of the action method in that controller.
This works for Rails 4 and should also work for older versions of Rails.

Comment: Does this includes sending user-given parameters to the destination controller/action triggering the controller's callbacks?

Comment: `redirect_to controller: :controllername, action: :actionname`

Comment: Any way to pass parameters to that? I am trying to get to a generic error page and send corresponding messages on the action being called. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One caveat, `controllername` should not contain "controller". For instance, if your controller is named `MyOtherController`/`my_other_controller.rb`, then you should use `redirect_to controller: :my_other, action: :index`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in routes.rb file

```
get :old_action, to: 'new_controller#new_action'
```